# How to make hibernation work on Shuttle SX58H7 (Intel X58 Express)?

Tags: hibernate, shuttle

I have a Shuttle SX58H7 computer (Intel X58 Express board, AMI BIOS version 08.00.16) with Intel Core i7 950 and GeForce GT 210 Silent (nvidia proprietary driver).

Under Karmic (64-bit), hibernation worked fine. Under Maverick, the computer goes to hibernation but when woken, USB and display don't come back and sshd doesn't respond, either. Sometimes when waking from basic sleep (as opposed to hibernation), sshd does come back and the computer can be reached from the network. IIRC, the regression happened when upgrading to Lucid.

Is there a know workaround that would restore the hibernation capability that existed under Karmic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9992908&postcount=33):

1. Add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"` in `/etc/default/grub`
2. Run `sudo update-grub`

*Note:* The above works in Ubuntu 10.10. However, it *breaks* hibernation in Ubuntu 11.04. In Ubuntu 11.04, make sure `acpi_sleep=nonvs` is *not* in the config and run `sudo update-grub`.